# Get message from Twilio REST API throws 'SmsMessages object is not callable'

Tags: python, twilio

I am trying to get a message object from the Twilio REST API, and it's not working.

I have a class method that creates and sends a sms message with Twilio. It looks something like this:

```
def send_sms(self, recipient, body):
    client = twilio.rest.TwilioRestClient(
        self._account_sid,
        self._auth_token)

    try:
        message = client.sms.messages.create(
            to=recipient,
            from_=self._from,
            body=body)
    except twilio.TwilioRestException as error:
        # do some stuff...

    return message
```

I have another class method that is supposed to get the message object from Twilio, so I can check the status:

```
def get_sms(self, sid):

    client = twilio.rest.TwilioRestClient(
        self._account_sid,
        self._auth_token)

    message = client.sms.messages(sid).fetch()
    return message
```

Unfortunately, my attempt to get the message using the sid is not working. The `message = client.sms.messages(sid).fetch()` line method throws an error: `TypeError: 'SmsMessages' object is not callable`.

This is frustrating, because according to the [docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/message) I am doing this correctly. *I have tried removing the `.sms.` from the line also!*

Comment: The helper library API changed between v5.x and 6.x and it looks like you might be mixing those API's up.  You're creating a `TwilioRestClient` which is what you'd do with the 5.x library, but then calling `fetch` like you would with the 6.x library.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out! Do you know where I can find documentation for v5.x?

Comment: Nevermind, I found where the toggle version button is. Not very clear, if you ask me!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I'll pass it along to our docs crew.

Answer (score 0):

I was mixing use of the `TwilioRestClient`, from the REST API v5.x, with use of `fetch()`, from the REST API v6.x. For future reference, there is a tiny version toggle button in the top right corner of the code explorer in the Twilio docs!